Issue with Syncing Date Slicer and Attendance Slicer in School Dataset
I'm working with a school dataset in Power BI, and I'm encountering an issue where I'm unable to synchronize the Date slicer with the Attendance slicer. My goal is to achieve dynamic interaction between the two slicers so that when one is adjusted, the other reflects the appropriate range, and the Student Table updates accordingly.
Desired Functionality:-
Date Slicer and Attendance Slicer Sync: I would like the Date slicer to dynamically adjust based on the selected Attendance time and vice versa.
Manual Adjustment: When I manually drag or change the Attendance time in the slicer, the Date slicer should display the actual corresponding dates, and the Student Table should show only the related data for those dates and attendance times.
Current Setup:
The TBL table has a Many-to-One relationship with the Calendar table based on the Date field.
I’ve tried creating DAX measures to capture the Min and Max values for both Date and Attendance, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired sync between the slicers.
Any guidance on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated. I've attached the PBIX file for reference and working purposes.
[Attach PBIX file] - https://github.com/dumbles/file/blob/main/Student_PBIX.pbix

In the file you provided the interactions between the Date Slicer and the Attendance Hour Slicer are set to No Filter. To fix this, do the following:

Click DATE SLICER.
Click the Format tab in the ribbon.
Click Edit Interactions.
Select Filter on Attendance Hour Slicer.


More information about interactions can be found here.

thanks for your reply, not sure if the Date slicer got changed by dragging the Attendance slicer slider, i want both to be interactive, not one or I'm missing some thing here,

@Black_Ruby perform these same steps but starting with the Attendance Slicer and setting the Date Slicer Interaction to Filter.
